# How to open content dialog without button click fron c# code to xaml code for UWp app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

While navigating next page that content dialogue should appear without button Click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > While navigating next page that content dialogue should appear without button Click.

When navigating to the next page, it will trigger [OnNavigatedTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto) method, you can display the content dialog in it without clicking the button.

Next page.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    DisplayNoWifiDialog();
}

private async void DisplayNoWifiDialog()
{
    ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog()
    {
        Title = "Next Page",
        Content = "Hello.",
        CloseButtonText = "Ok"
    };

    await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
 }
```

**Update:**

If your content dialog written in xaml, you can subscribe the Loaded event and show the dialog in it.

Next page.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentDialog x:Name="MyContentDialog"
                   Title="Hello"
                   Content="Welcome"
                   CloseButtonText="Cancel">
    </ContentDialog>
</StackPanel>
```

Next page.cs:

```
public BlankPage1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += BlankPage1_Loaded;
}

private async void BlankPage1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyContentDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: Have you solved issue? Do you have other questions?